# c++ what is the type of T[] in template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I have a question about the implementation of `std::remove_extent` (visual studio 11)

```
    template<class _Ty>
        struct remove_extent
        {
        typedef _Ty type;
        };

    template<class _Ty, unsigned int _Ix>
        struct remove_extent<_Ty[_Ix]>
        {
        typedef _Ty type;
        };

    template<class _Ty>
        struct remove_extent<_Ty[]> //what for?
        {
        typedef _Ty type;
        };
```

I just tried this: `std::cout <<  typeid(int[]).name() << '\n';`

and the output is： `int [0]`, so I presume `_Ty[]` stands for `_Ty[0]`.

but what is the purpose of specializing for `_T[0]`, I think the second case has handled for that.

Also, I really doubt that if `T [0]` is a valid type, If so, in which case whould you use that?

Comment: `T[0]` is not a valid type, which is why the name mangling grammar on your platform reused its dynamic type name to represent `T[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`T[]` is an array of unknown size; an incomplete type, different from any sized array type. It seems that your compiler, validly but somewhat confusingly, uses the otherwise invalid `T[0]` as the string representation of the type.

So this specialisation is needed since it won't be covered by the partial specialisation for sized arrays.

> If so, in which case whould you use that?

You wouldn't use an array of zero size, since that's not a valid type.

You can use incomplete types (including arrays of unknown size) in various places, such as variable declarations. For example:

```
extern int array[];                           // declaration with incomplete type
std::remove_extent<decltype(array)>::type x;  // OK, gives "int"
array[3] = 42;                                // OK, array decays to pointer

template <size_t N> size_t size(int (&a)[N]) {return N;}
std::cout << size(array) << "\n";             // Error, needs complete type

// somewhere else
int array[17];                                // definition with complete type
std::cout << size(array) << "\n";             // OK, size is known
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I still don't understand what an array of unknown size stands for? And how to pass a unsized array to that template? it seems like that std::remove_extent<int[]> falls to the base case.

Comment: @Frahm: I've given some examples of what you can do with an array of unknown size.

Answer (score 1):

> and the output is： `int [0]`, so I presume `_Ty[]` stands for `_Ty[0]`.

No, it's not the same, as Mike Seymour's answer says.  It looks like a problem with your compiler's `type_info` name if it says it's the same.

> Also, I really doubt that if `T [0]` is a valid type, If so, in which case whould you use that?

Some compilers allow it as an extension, so this is OK on such compilers:

```
typedef int empty_array[0];   // typedef for int[0]
int* p = new empty_array;
```

Comment: The type info name can be anything… I'm surprised `name()` is returning such a human-readable string on any platform. It's not a problem with the name, it's a problem with reading too much into it, besides being a unique NTBS for each type.

Comment: Good point about it only needing to be a unique NTBS, and if the platform doesn't support the zero-length-array extension then the string `"T[0]"` is not taken and can be used for `T[]`